# Entity framework: changing mapped foreign key from required to nullable

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, foreign-key-relationship

I'm trying to change the specifically mapped foreign keys from required to nullable, but for some reason entity framework migration doesn't register the change. Specifically what I have done is change the following code from

```
public int Test_TestId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Test_TestId")]
public Test Test { get; set; }
```

to

```
public int? Test_TestId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("Test_TestId")]
public Test Test { get; set; }
```

Changing the database field to nullable manually makes entity ignore every result with Test_TestId = null.

Is there something that can be done about this?

Comment: You are using code first ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Do your migrations pick up on other changes. I have made this exact change many times and the migration process has never failed to pick up on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider Overriding the `OnModelCreating` method inside your DbContext

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DataContext,Configuration>());

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```